# React Native Simulator/Emulator low performance

Tags: performance, react-native, android-emulator, ios-simulator

I have weird problem with iOS Simulator / Android Emulator when testing application made in React Native. On some devices, performance is very slow, sometimes it cannot even connect to localhost API. It happens only on specific devices, for example, on iPhone 6 everything works fine, but iPhone X works very slow. Other built in apps on those simulators like Safari have no performance issues, only mine, tested one.

It is not problem with "Slow Animations" toggle.

Comment: Did you turn on the remote debugger?

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the issue... I did not know that it has to be debbuged remotely for optimal performance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, The issue of react native app's performance is so low even on the iOS caused by **remote debugger was turned on**.

Also, worth to be mentioned, the sluggish iOS performance indicate more bigger problem on your React Native app, another common root cause:

1. Expensive Js operation
2. Lots of `console.log`.
3. Component re-render.
4. Bad Animation Implementation.